# How to get AWS EC2/Sagemaker instance used time by instance type and day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I want to get instance used time by instance type and day, in EC2 and Sagemaker service,

But in AWSCUR it seems no value of instance running time(hour/minute/second),

How can I get the instance actual used time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see daily (or even hourly if you opt-in) cost and usage by instance type with:
`aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2021-10-26,End=2021-10-27 --granularity DAILY --metrics "UsageQuantity" "BlendedCost" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=INSTANCE_TYPE`
Note that SageMaker instance types names starts with: `ml.*`

To view things in the finest resolution you'll need to produce detailed billing reports (DBR): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/detailed-billing.html
It will generates CSV reports in S3, which you could query with Athena using SQL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/cur-query-athena.html